# After I used the "after" function, my method prototype doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that "creates" a select (using the after), and I'd like to, after its creation, the select would be open. I searched the internet and found the following method prototype:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.openSelect = function ()
    {
        return this.each(function (idx, domEl) {
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                event.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                domEl.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else if (element.fireEvent) {
                domEl.fireEvent("onmousedown");
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

This prototype worked well, an example of its working conditions:

html:

```
    <select id="selecttest">
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>
```

js:

```
jQuery("#selecttest").openSelect();
```

However when I tried using this inside my function that creates selects, it didn't work.

Look at my html:

```
       <div id="disciplinas_edit_div">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">Leciona as disciplinas</div>

            </div>
            <div id="disciplinas_edit"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="maisdisciplina_edit();" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Disciplina
            </button>
        </div>
```

My JS:

```
function maisdisciplina_edit() {
    jQuery("#disciplinas_edit").after(
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-lg-10">' +
                '<select class="form-control" name="disciplinas[]">' +
                    '<option>exemple</option>' +
                '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-2">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick="menosdisciplina(this);"> ' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>' +
                '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>');
    jQuery(jQuery("select[name^=disciplinas]")[0]).openSelect();//this line didn't work on this method

}
```

I tested that line in the console and it worked, it opened the last added line. I tried putting that line in a function that is called after the button is clicked, it also worked opening the last added line. Why doesn't it works on my method and how do I solve my problem with automatically opening the select?

Comment: Oops, edited my suggestion. Meant to be: `$("#disciplinas_edit").after(your-mark-up-goes-here).promise().done(function(){$("select[name^=disciplinas]")[0]).openSelect()});`

Comment: console msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL =/

Comment: replacing the $ with jQuery as you've got it as well?

Comment: again =/

i try this too: jQuery("#disciplinas_edit").after(...).promise().done(function(){jQuery(jQuery("select[name^=disciplinas]")[0]).openSelect()}); (and same msg appear)

Comment: What you meant is not right. I try this (indented): jQuery("#disciplinas_edit").after(...).promise().done( function () {jQuery(jQuery("select[name^=disciplinas]")[0]).openSelect();}); The error is gone but still the same problem.